# What is the point of using then() in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

For example, I have the code:

```
self.selectSongsAlbum = function(album) {
                        return self.query(
                                "SELECT * FROM Musics WHERE Album LIKE '%"
                                        + album + "%'").then(function(result) {
                            return self.fetchAll(result);
                        });
                    };
```

I dont really get the ideas of using then() here.  Can someone explain  to me that when do we usually use then() and how?

Comment: When working with asynchronous calls in JavaScript you need to use then() in order to execute code after code that returns a promise otherwise the code would run right after each other and any value you need from the first call would not be ready for the second call. In your example you need the results from query to pass into fetchall

Comment: Google `Promise MDN` and read

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

`.then()` is used in asynchronous environments and is part of the promise API. It promises you a result, where you can trust it to return either as success (then) or as error (error).

See the link I shared or this extract from it

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.

Answer (score 0):

From the angularjs documentation: [The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.
>
> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using promise chaining). It also notifies via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise cannot be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.